# Can't call base class method even though I have a pointer to it (Decorator)?

Tags: c++, templates, decorator

I have a template class that I've subclassed with a pointer to it (Decorator pattern).  I added a `getBase()` call to return the pointer to the base class for any further subclasses.  However, when I use that `getBase()` and call the base classes only method, I get a linker error that it can't find the symbol for that method in the intervening (Decorator) class?

Like this:

```
template <typename T> class B {    
  public:
    typedef std::auto_ptr<T> MYFUN( 
      std::istream&, const std::string&, const std::string& );

  public:
    B<T>( MYFUN* p );
    auto_ptr<T> fun( istream& );

  private:
    MYFUN *fptr;
};

template <typename T>
class D : public class B<T>
{
  D( typename B<T>::MYFUN *fPtr, B<T> *providedBase );
  //Looks like B
  B* getBase() { return base_ ; }
  private:
    B* base_;
};

template <typename T>
class Dagain : public class D<T>
{
  //Looks like D
  auto_ptr<T> fun( istream& );
};

auto_ptr<T>
Dagain::fun( istream& is )
{
  this->getBase()->fun( is );
}
```

Note that there is no definition for `fun( istream& )` in `D<T>`.  The intention is for the client to use the pointer to the base to call `B<T>::fun( istream& )`

When the client constructs a `Dagain` object, the linker says (basically):

`Client.o:

(.data.rel.ro. --stuff--

[vtable for D<T>]:

undefined reference to

'D<T>::fun( basic_istream<char, char_traits<char> >&)'`

But, I'm not calling **D**'s definition of `fun(istream&)`...  it doesn't even have one!  I'm using the pointer directly to the base class...   When I add a definition for `D<T>::fun(istream&)` things work, but I don't understand why?

Comment: This code contains too much unrelated stuff and too many compilations errors (probably as a result of trimming it to this question) to be seriously considered. If you want a real answer, I recommend editing the question with code that can really compile and minimally shows the problem.

Comment: I apologize. I have to type all this from memory as I have no Internet connection at work.  I'll attempt it again later after I reduce the problem to it's essentials and I can compile it.  Then I'll repost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to specify the template parameter in the template definition. Furthermore you had some more errors. Here is the working code:

```
template <typename T> class B {
  public:
    typedef std::auto_ptr<T> MYFUN(
      std::istream&, const std::string&, const std::string& );

  public:
    B<T>( MYFUN* p );
    auto_ptr<T> fun( istream& );

  private:
    MYFUN *fptr;
};

template <typename T>
class D : public B<T>
{
  D( typename B<T>::MYFUN *fPtr, B<T> *providedBase );
  //Looks like B
  B<T>* getBase() { return base_ ; }
  private:
    B<T>* base_;
};

template <typename T>
class Dagain : public D<T>
{
  //Looks like D
  auto_ptr<T> fun( istream& );
};

template <typename T>
auto_ptr<T>
Dagain<T>::fun( istream& is )
{
  this->getBase()->fun( is );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C++ expert and not sure if this has anything to do with templates, but if we ignore the templates, I think part of your problem might be that fun() in B is not virtual.

When you call getBase() you get a static type of B*, and then when you invoke fun() on it you're getting the version from B rather than the version in DAgain. I would think that the linker would complain over the fact that you have not defined the version for B (and thus for D). The fact that fun() is overridden in DAgain would not suffice since the binding is static.

Another option is that returning B* rather than B* may be the issue, but I haven't played with C++ enough recently.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your `getBase` is returning the wrong type. It should be returning the correct type of the base class:

```
template <typename T>
class D : public class B<T>
{
  ...
  //Looks like B
  B<T>* getBase() { return base_ ; }
  private:
    B<T>* base_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you call a "base" actually isn't -- D has a real B base (due to inheritance) and a fake one via that pointer.  As to why the compiler is whining about a vtable when you appear to have no virtuals at all, that's weird -- you sure you don't have a virtual somewhere?

Comment: i think he is trying to do something like javas' Thread <-> Runnable. storing what runnable's run method is actually invoked. "this" or "another runnable"